82 bytes Mint accounts
In an 82 bytes Mint account what are the first 4 bytes and the last 4 bytes.
00-03 (4 bytes) : ??
04-35 (32 bytes): Mint Authority
36-43 (8 bytes) : Supply
44    (1 byte)  : Decimals
45    (1 byte)  : Initialized
46-49 (4 bytes) : ??
50-81 (32 bytes): Freeze Authority

If you talk about the Token Program Mint (program id TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA) then it's the best check the Mint state definition at
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/token-client-v0.10.0/token/program/src/state.rs#L18
From there we can see there is no Discriminator and directly there is used the mint_authority: COption<Pubkey> and the deserialization and serialization is then implemented down in the code.
The COption is defined at the Solana Program at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/v1.18.14/sdk/program/src/program_option.rs#L15 but the serialization is within here which is defined as 4 bytes data
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/token-client-v0.10.0/token/program/src/state.rs#L255
So that's the answer. First 4 bytes is either [1,0,0,0] as saying the next bytes will be valid authority pubkey or [0,0,0,0] as the mint authority is not set. I.e., the first 4 bytes is data serialization of COption data structure.
The same for the last bytes which is not defined correctly in the question. It will be
46-49 (4 bytes) COption data

50-82 (32 bytes): Freeze Authority


Thanks, it seems to be right.

0-3 (4 bytes) and 46-49 (4 bytes) both take [1,0,0,0] or [0,0,0,0] as value, but in both cases you can have wallet or not. So, this case is possible: [0,0,0,0] => Wallet

I edit my question to write down bytes as you pointed (so that I don't make other people get confused).

It seems that:
0-3 (4 bytes): Mint authority enabled.
46-49 (4 bytes): Freeze authority enabled.
